# Ajax call does not trigger on selecting an option with script from dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to make a chrome-extension to automate a little daily-chore at my job. So this site has a standard dropDown input something like this below.

```
<select id="branchList">
    <option value="3">KATHMANDU</option>
    <option value="18">DELHI</option>
    <option value="24">BEIJING</option>
</select>
```

When I manually click on one of the options it triggers an ajax call and loads the portion of the page with new data. But if I programmatically try to select the option it does not trigger the ajax call. Below is the code I use to select an option which selects the option but does not trigger the ajax call as expected.

```
document.querySelector("#branchList").value = "18"
```

I also tried the code below to programmatically click on the element but it still does not trigger the ajax call.

```
document.querySelector("#branchList").options[1]
```

Bottom-line is - I'm looking for a way to trigger an ajax call when I select an option from the dropdown with JavaScript.

---

**EDIT** - using `dispatchEvent` as suggested in the comment.

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#branchList").options[1]
let event = new Event("click");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Use dispatchEvent to send `change` event to the element.

Comment: ok this is new to me. exploring it now.

Comment: @wOxxOm any idea why the code still fails to trigger the ajax call ? please see the edited question... at the bottom.

Comment: `click` should be created as `MouseEvent`, AFAIK. Also I suggested using `change`, not `click`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger the change event.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('branchList')


select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log('change')
  //here should be the ajax call
})

function changeSelectValue(num){
 
  select.value = num
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

changeSelectValue(18)
```

```html
<select id="branchList">
    <option value="3">KATHMANDU</option>
    <option value="18">DELHI</option>
    <option value="24">BEIJING</option>
</select>
```